# Почему можно получить доступ к static переменной будучи в другом файле?

Tags: c++, static, стандарт

Header.h

```
class A
{
public:
    static int x;
};
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
int A::x = 0;
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::x;
}
```

static устанавливает внутреннюю связь к переменной. Так как переменная  `x` определена в Source.cpp, то как я могу получить доступ к ней будучи в Main.cpp?

Comment: В данном контексте слово `static` означает, что это член *класса*, а не *объекта*, т.е. это совсем не то же, как если бы вы определили глобальную переменную как `static`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаем (https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), что значит ключевое слово `static`

> `static` - статическая или потоковая длительность хранения и внутреннее связывание (или внешнее связывание для статических элементов класса, не находящихся в анонимном пространстве имён).

Вот потому, что для статических элементов класса это внешнее связывание, вы и можете обращаться к этой переменной в другом файле.

Answer (score 3):

Ключевое слово статической переменной **static** позаимствовано из языка Си и при включении в определении класса поменяла тип компоновки на *противоположный*. *(из внутреннего на внешний)* Так как элементы класса должны быть доступны в любом отделе программы. Если бы вы попробовали указать точно, что эта переменная статическая в Си смысле, то получите ошибку :

```
error: ‘static’ may not be used when defining 
  (as opposed to declaring) a static data member [-fpermissive]
static int A::x = 0;
```

То-есть можно определить переменную статической в Си смысле *(в каждом отделе **свой** внутренний экземпляр)* **или строго исключительно ⊻** в C++ смысле *(**одна** для всех членов класса и даже может быть приватной)*.

Comment: `То-есть можно определить переменную статической в Си смысле (много экземпляров) или строго исключительно ⊻ в C++ смысле.` Тоже неверно. `static` в Си определяет режим компоновки для переменной или функции в глобальной области и класс хранения в теле функции. `static` в классе  меняет тип хранилища а не режим компоновки, сохраняя остальные смыслы неизменными. Член класса не может иметь локальный режим компоновки ("внутреннне связывание"), его имя должно быть доступно, т.к. стандарт не запрещает определять  функции-члены класса в разных модулях и они обязаны имень доступ к этой переменной.

Comment: `"НЕ запрещает определять функции-члены класса в разных модулях"` - скорее всего *запрещает* @Swift-FridayPie

Comment: режим компоновки как раз и меняет наоборот @Swift-FridayPie

Comment: А у полей класса самих по себе разве есть linkage? Вряд ли, в этом согласен с Swift - Friday Pie.

Comment: [Статические члены (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/static-members-cpp?view=msvc-170) - цитата : "Такие статические члены имеют внешнюю компоновку;" @HolyBlackCat разговор идёт как раз про статические члены. *Что такое linkage?*

Comment: Я имел в виду нестатические. У вас написано, что у них внутренняя компоновка, а я подозреваю, что вообще никакая.

Comment: `static int x;` - внутренняя vs `class C{static int x;};` - внешняя : вот в чём разница @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Все, понял идею.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  алекс опередил, но добавлю - т.к. эти переменные работают аналогично глобальным, логично предположить, что да. К нестатическим мы обращаемся через `this`  а не через глобальный идентификатор в таблице. В этом и была видимо идея Страуструпа - доступ к ним организуется на момент компиляции, поэтому  static

Comment: @AlexGlebe я спокойно могу написать часть определений в одном .cpp а часть в другом. Хоть по модулю на функцию создать.